# Wordpress Permalinks 404 error with HTTPS host

Tags: php, wordpress, https, url-rewriting, permalinks

My new permalinks continue displaying a 404 error on my site even after adding the AllowOverride and Rewrite modules parameters. Here is my default-ssl.conf file :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

ServerAdmin vincent.zzz@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/zzz
ServerName zzz.com.vn
ServerAlias www.zzz.com.vn

<Directory "/var/www/zzz">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>

<Location />
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
</Location>     

#end of custon stuff.....
```

And here is the normal http part of my apache2.conf file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName zzz.com.vn
DocumentRoot /var/www/zzz
<Directory "/var/www/zzz">

    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    #force SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent]

</Directory>
```

Would anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that mod_rewrite is enabled? Is there a symbolic link to rewrite.load in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`?
You can enable the mod with:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```